# Access Report #Error Text Message

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm attempting to build a summary report in Access with some custom statistics based on a daily query. However, I'm running into some difficulties. When I use a report built off said query, I get the same exact number regardless of the formula.

I'm building a formula to count text values in a field or count all responses  in a field but the formula will always return 18 as a value (the total number of records) even when I know it to be false for the formula. Alternatively, I will create a blank report and no matter what I do either receive an #Error or #Name? value in the textbox. I have checked and the name from the control is not any name in formula or anywhere else - I normally rename it Text0 or Demo.

The formula I've been attempting to use is

```
=Count(IIf([Daily_Numbers_Query].[Signed_Card] Is Not Null,1,0));
```

Where Daily_Numbers_Query refers to the query and Signed_Card refers to the field I want to examine from that query. I want it to tell my the number of records for which Signed_Card has a value and is not null.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said the query is in the report's RecordSource, then just need to use the correct false return. Also, probably don't need the query name prefix.

`=Count(IIf([Signed_Card] Is Not Null, 1, Null))`

or

`=Count(IIf(Not IsNull([Signed_Card]), 1, Null))`

or

`=Sum(IIf([Signed_Card] Is Not Null, 1, 0))`

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I spent about 12 hours this week banging my head over this - can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

`Count` is an aggregate function in SQL, but you can't use it directly in an expression.

For this you use Domain functions: `DCount`, `DSum`, ...

In this case the easiest would be:

```
=DCount("*", "Daily_Numbers_Query", "[Signed_Card] Is Not Null")
```

If you wanted to use `IIf`, you'd have to use `DSum`:

```
=DSum(IIf([Daily_Numbers_Query].[Signed_Card] Is Not Null,1,0))
```

Comment: SQL aggregate functions are possible in expression. The DSum suggested is not correct syntax.